# Error 401 when trying to access Sharepoint using typescript

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, axios

I am trying to access sharepoint using axios library. i have already generated the token before, and im using this code to get the title of the site but i keep getting error 401 when trying to access. does anyone know how to solve this?

```
function getExcelFile(fileUrl: string, token: string) {
    axios.get(fileUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }})
    .then((response) => {
        // Extract the site title from the response
        const siteTitle = response.data.Title;
        console.log(`SharePoint site title: ${siteTitle}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error getting SharePoint site title: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `fileUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error indicates that the API audience of your access token does not match the API resource you are calling. When getting an access token, make sure your `scope` is set to: `https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/.default`

To parse the access token your `aud` claim should be:

[image]

Comment: Would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?